# ActiveRecord/PostgreSQL - GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to do this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging) on Tagging with my Rails 3.2 app on Postgres.  I have it working excepting for the tag cloud functionality.  However, I'm adding a layer by looking to form tag clouds based on tags an user created.

I'm trying to adapt/revise the code from the Railscast:

```
def self.tag_counts
  Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
    joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
end
```

but when I run this, I get the PG error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "tags.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) a...
```

Here's how the models look:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :trades
has_many :taggings, :through => :trades
has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
```

**trade.rb**

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
```

**tagging.rb**

```
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :trade
```

**tag.rb**

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :trades, through: :taggings
```

If someone could help lend a hand in revising the query to do a count on a user's tags that would be most appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: `tags.*, COUNT(...)` is suspect.

Comment: Do you need the table "tags" at all for that query? Does the SQL query `select tag_id, count(tag_id) from taggings group by tag_id;` return the right data?

Comment: oh, it needs tags because tags.name contains the actual tag word.  taggings links trades to tags.

Comment: If all you need from that table is tags.name, try 'select("tags.name, count' and group("taggings.tag_id, tags.name"). That might work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in the Rails Cast you sent *SQLite* is used as a database while you're using *postgres* ; So the problem is that database like *SQLite* and *MySQL* let you add fields that are **not** in the **Group BY** clause but *postgres* don't.

So You've two options

1. you use counter_cache option in belong_to association in your tagging model.
2. replace join with includes like the following.

   Tagging.includes(:tag).select("taggings.tag_id, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").group("taggings.tag_id")